# How to parse specific data in a string line?

Tags: vb.net

What makes my question different than many others already asked is that I know how to parse data with delimiters such as a comma or space, but I'm unsure how to parse data that is separated by spaces but also contain spaces. This is an example line:
M 9 12.02 Adam Productions Inc

So I need to parse "M", 9, 12.02, and "Adam Productions Inc" out to different variables but I'm not sure how to do that. Here is my code to parse by spaces.

```
Dim contents() As String = strRawFile.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(" ")}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Obviously this does parse my first 3 pieces of data, but then it tears apart the 4th piece. How can I modify my code to overcome this?

Desired Result:

M

9

12.02

Adam Productions Inc

Comment: `dim result = [Your String].Split(" ", 4, StringSplitOptions.None)` -- If you're the one who decided to generate this non-format, rethink the whole thing and use a proper format as JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split it out and then join together items from the 4th element of the array until the array length.  This assumes that there will not be any embedded spaces in the first 3 items.

Comment: The [String.Split(Char, Int32, StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char-system-int32-system-stringsplitoptions)) overload "Splits a string into a maximum number of substrings...", so that could be used with no need to join the elements together afterwards. (As shown in the [comment by Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71285680/how-to-parse-specific-data-in-a-string-line#comment126007146_71285680).)